# Enable Console.log Output To Webpack When Using HMR

Tags: logging, console, webpack, webpack-hmr

I am using Webpack's HMR.

When I run webpack from the Terminal, I get all of Weback's own output, but any of my own logging within the application is only written to the browser console and not to webpack's output in the Terminal (I am using [LogLevel](https://github.com/pimterry/loglevel), but the same is true of a `console.log()`) . Is is possible to pipe console output to Webpack so that it is displayed in the Terminal?